# Is there a more pythonic way of writing this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code and it works. I wanted to have other thoughts on how the code can be improved thanks.

The main objective of the code is to determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

```
def hh(s):
    o = True 
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if (s[i+1] <= s[i]):
            o = False
    return o
```

```
def solution(sequence):
    o = False
    s = sequence 
    
    for i in range(len(s)):
        d = s.pop(i) 
        if hh(s):
            o = True
        s.insert(i,d)
    return o
```

```
solution([1,3,2,1]) should return false
solution([1,3,2]) should return true
```

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you expect the code to do, beyond returning those exact two values in those exact two cases?

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be improved using early returns. It looks cleaner and may slightly improve performance (depending on how large the list is).

```
def hh(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if (s[i+1] <= s[i]):
            return False
    return True

def solution(sequence):
    s = sequence 
    for i in range(len(s)):
        d = s.pop(i) 
        if hh(s):
            return True
        s.insert(i,d)
    return False
```